# Chain rule question-multiple functions in one equation.

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

We have been provided with:

$$Z=xf(y/x)+yg(y/x), $$

and been asked to obtain $Z_{xx},\ Z_{xy}$ and $ Z_{yy}$.

I am well aware that I will be differentiating $Z$ with respect to $x$. I've been provided with an answer from a group member but the working out is very lacking, hence I am quite stuck.

$$Z_x=y/(x+y)^2.$$

What has been done to achieve this?

Comment: any information about $f(y/x)$ and $g(y/x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the given information we obtain

$$Z=xf(y/x)+yg(y/x)\implies Z_x=f(y/x)+xf_x(y/x)\frac{-y}{x^2}+yg_x(y/x)\frac{-y}{x^2}=\\=f(y/x)-\frac{y}xf_x(y/x)-\frac{y^2}{x^2}g_x(y/x)$$